# Safari Toggle Map and Street view not triggering on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, safari

Alright so I'm going to try to explain this the best I can.

I have a toggle map view and streetview tab section of my site and it works on every single browser apart from safari on a mobile or tablet device.

The next two images are what it looks like when it is working:
[image]

[image]

So this is what it normally looks like not much use me showing you it working but gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

This next image is what it does when you click "streetview" on an ipad or iphone using safari. Note it does work on other browsers.

[image]

however if I press the streetview toggle button again then it works fine...

Things I've tried to do:

1) I thought that this might be due to a hover effect however I have removed this from the css and hasn't had any effect. 
2) I've also removed the foundation off canvas to see if there was a hidden element over the top of it preventing it from doing what its supposed to!
3) I've also messed around with touch events with no luck as from what I understand safari doesn't support these yet.

I have done more on this but tbh I can't remember them all!

The Jquery:

```
    var initialize = function () {
var streetView = new google.maps.LatLng( {{$data->lat .' , '.$data->long}} );
var panoramaOptions = {
  position: streetView,
  pov: {
    heading: 165,
    pitch: 0
  },
  zoom: 1,
  zoomControl:false,
  scrollwheel: false
};
var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('street-canvas'),
    panoramaOptions);
myPano.setVisible(true);
};

$('.street-canvas-btn').on('click touchend', initialize ).preventDefault();

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

AS you can see i've added both click and touchend to the on function. Oh btw I've also put this through an alert function to see if when it is clicked it is getting clicked. It worked with my disbelief! Alerting some writing i entered.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="property-single__map">

<div class="row">
    <div class="columns large-offset-3 large-6 property-single__map__col">

        <!-- Tab Heads -->
        <dl class="tabs tabs--maps" data-tab>
          <dd class="active map-canvas"><a class="br-left" href="#panel1">Map View</a></dd>
          <dd><a href="#panel2" class="br-right street-canvas-btn">Street View</a></dd>
        </dl>   
        <!--\ Tab Heads -->

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Tab Content -->
<div class="tabs-content tabs__content--maps">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1">
    <aside>
        {{ $map['html'] }}
    </aside>
    <div class="google-map" data-lat="{{{$data->lat}}}" data-long="{{{$data->long}}}"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2">
    <aside>
        <div id="street-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 480px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></div>
    </aside>
    <div class="google-map" data-lat="{{{$data->lat}}}" data-long="{{{$data->long}}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is as much information I can give you so please let me know if you have experienced this problem before and if you might have a solution as it has come to the point of driving me mental!

Many thanks

Comment: not one person has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is to anyone that has problems with a toggle map and streetview. This literally took me 4 days to figure out.

Here is the jquery needed to fix my issue:
            var initialize = function () {
        var streetView = new google.maps.LatLng( {{$data->lat .' , '.$data->long}} );
        var panoramaOptions = {
          position: streetView,
          pov: {
            heading: 165,
            pitch: 0
          },
          zoom: 1,
          zoomControl:false,
          scrollwheel: false
        };
        var myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('street-canvas'),
            panoramaOptions);
            myPano.setVisible(true);
        };

```
    $('.street-canvas-btn').on('click touchend', function (event, tab) {

        setTimeout(initialize, 300);

    });
```

Basically what is happening is the setTimeout is giving your device more time to do all the other things you've already asked it to do. This allows after the touch has happened to then perform the function.